# Insert data in to ErrorLog table when an entry fails in another table

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

Hi all I am using entity framework where I am inserting some data in to a table as follows

```
try
{
     context.tableName.AddRange(entity);
     context.SaveChanges();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ErrorLog error = new ErrorLog();
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ex.Message))
       error.ErrorMessage = ex.Message.ToString();
    if (ex.InnerException != null)
       error.InnerException = ex.InnerException.ToString();
    error.StackTrace = ex.StackTrace;
    error.ErrorSource = ex.Source;
   _errorRepository.SaveErrorLog(error);

    return false;
}
```

Here is the code which I am having my in another interface

```
public void SaveErrorLog(ErrorLog errorLog)
{
context.ErrorLog.Add(errorLog);
context.SaveChanges();
}
```

But while saving it is  throwing an error so how to insert data in to error log table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new **DBContext** for error repository, then it will work, because if you used shared context between all repositories, then shared context will always have error-generated entities and they will never allow you to save the context, for this first you need to remove the entity from entity set and then it works in shared context